# How to add line break in downloaded text file using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to download inside div content in text format.

I can able to download inside div content in txt format but all the contents are same line .

I need to add the line break in each element.

```js
function download() {
        var a = document.body.appendChild(
            document.createElement("a")
        );
        a.download = "export.txt";
        a.href = "data:text/html," + document.getElementById("show-data").innerHTML;
        a.click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-data">
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>Three</p>
</div>
<button onClick="download()">Download</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1L2vmdhu/

Comment: didn't get it, Its having line breaks

Comment: @VenkateshKonatham Update the questions

Comment: please check my answer below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

please try with below example, as you are passing data in the form of url you have to encode new line characters which will make it work and another thing is you are trying to download as text so change content type to "text/plain"

```js
 function download() {
        var a = document.body.appendChild(
            document.createElement("a")
        );
        var textToWrite = document.getElementById("show-data").innerText;
        a.download = "export.txt"; 
        textToWrite = textToWrite.replace(/\n/g, "%0D%0A"); 
        a.href = "data:text/plain," + textToWrite;
        a.click();
    }
```

```html
  <div id="show-data">
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>Three</p>
</div>
    <button onClick="download()">Download</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

EDIT.

You can add \r\n to the end of all lines and the use the encodeURIComponent on the text output before outputting it to the text file.
I added it here.

https://jsfiddle.net/1L2vmdhu/11/

I changed the javascript like this to make it work.

```
function download() {
    var a = document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement("a")
    );
    a.download = "export.txt";

    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var b = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        console.log(list[i].innerHTML);
        b += list[i].innerHTML + "\r\n";
    }
    b = encodeURIComponent(b);
    a.href = "data:text/html," + b;
    a.click();
}
```